# how to avoid looking css property using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is some content in html page and one of div style for that is like below:

```
.class1{
property1:value1;
property2:value2;
property3:value3;
property4:value4;
}
```

I want to avoid applying css property property1 into concerned content and rest property property2, property3, property4 are welcomed.

I want to avoid applying property1 and don't want to change the css file.

Also I don't want to use as below:

```
$('.class1').css('property1','some different value');
```

I just want to avoid property1 using code. 
Please tell me how I done using jquery or js.
----------------------Edited------------------------

I don't want to generate any inline css on run time.
I am looking ui code some thing like as below:

```
 $('.ui-resizable').css('position').disable()
```

Comment: Why don't you want to do those things? If you can't do them, what can you do?

Comment: add `.class1` again with only `property1`, but this time with the property's default value.

Comment: i think you need to give inline style on class1 that will be replace the value

Answer (score 0):

There is not function avaialbe to do that , one way to achieve this is

```
$('.class1').css('property1','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set an inline style on the element that negates the property or makes it what you want. No jQuery necessary. Inline styles will always override inherited styles.

```
<div class="class1" style="margin:whatever"></div>
```

Comment: don't want to use any inline css!

Comment: Can I ask why? Inline CSS isn't dirty or anything. It's a perfectly legitimate way of accomplishing some tasks. Obviously what you're trying to do here is a hack to begin with - why not just create a new class without that property?

Answer (score 0):

Make another class "class2" with css and use

```
/* CSS */
.class2{
property1:value1;
}

//JQuery
$('div').removeClass('class1').addClass('class2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Preserve the value of property1 as:

```
var p1 = $('.class1').css('property1');
```

Now apply changes to the class as necessary.

Finally, restore the value of property1 as:

```
$('.class1').css('property1',p1);
```